# Converting a Character String to a Float

Tags: c, casting, floating-point-conversion

I'm trying to take the user input, which is a character string, and convert it to a float. In my case, `gas` keeps being printed as `55.000000` when the user enters `7` - I'd like it to be printed as `7.0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    char gas_gallons;
    float gas;
    printf("Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline: ");
    scanf("%c", &gas_gallons);

    while (!isdigit(gas_gallons))
    {
        printf("\nYou need to enter a digit. Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline: ");
        scanf("%c", &gas_gallons);
        }
    if (isdigit(gas_gallons))
    {
        printf("\nHello %c", gas_gallons);
        gas = gas_gallons;
        printf("\nHello f", gas);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo in last printf. And learn about printf format string syntax. That would help.

Comment: Your input is a single char, not a "character string" (if that would exist in C - you most likely mean a character array).

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this?  It's much simpler.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int gas;
    printf("Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline.\n : ");
    //use the %d specifier to get an integer.  This is more direct.
    //It will also allow the user to order more than 9 gallons of gas.
    scanf("%d", &gas);
    printf("\nHello %d", gas);//prints integer value of gas
    //Using the .1f allows  you to get one place beyond the decimal
    //so you get the .0 after the integer entered.
    printf("\nHello %.1f\n", (float) gas);//print floating point 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He wants `gas` to be a `float`, not an `int`.  But the general idea is right; `%c` is not the correct format to use.  Though, having said that, an integer may make more sense, but you should explain the changes you've made, not simply make them.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> In my case, gas keeps being printed as `55.000000` when the user enters `7`

When the user enters `7` as input the digit `7` is stored as the character in `gas_gallons`. The decimal value of the character `7` is `55` in ASCII encoding. You can see the decimal values of other characters in ASCII encoding at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and many other places on the web.

When you use:

```
 gas = gas_gallons;
```

the integer value of `gas_gallons` is, i.e. 55, is assigned to `gas`. That explains why you get `55.000000` as the output when you print `gas`.

You can fix the problem many ways. Here are a couple of suggestions.

**Option 1**

Convert the digit to a number by using:

```
 gas = gas_gallons - '0';
```

**Option 2**

Discard the code to read the number of gallons of gasoline as a digit and converting the digit to a number. Using a digit is also limiting since you cannot have `10` or `12.5` as input.

Read the number of gallons of gasoline as a number directly. With this approach, your input can be a any floating point number that can be represented by a `float`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   float num_gallons;

   while ( 1 )
   {
      printf("Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline: ");

      // Read the number of gallons of gas.
      // If reading is successful, break of the loop.
      if (scanf("%f", &num_gallons) == 1 )
      {
         break;
      }

      // There was an error.
      // Read and discard the rest of the line in the input
      // stream.
      scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

      printf("There was an error in reading the gallons of gasoline.\n");
   }

   printf("\nHello %f\n", num_gallons);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII-characters `'0'`-`'9'` do not have the integer values 0-9. You can find the appropriate value by subtracting `'0'`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to float you can use `atof` (ASCII to float) function included in `stdlib.h`.
Here is the full declaration of this function: `double atof(const char *str)`
so you can do a simple cast
`gas = (float) atof(gas_gallons);`